# Can auto deduction add implicitly constness?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, visual-c++-2015

Consinder the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct foo { std::string value; };
inline foo bar() { return { "42" }; }

std::string my_func() {
    auto &x = bar();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return x.value;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << my_func() << std::endl;  
}
```

Compiling it both [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4cf058ebc9822848) and [CLANG](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd11aa8d926d23e8) emit, most probably rightfully, the same error:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'foo&'
>   from an rvalue of type 'foo'

However, to my surprise it compiles and runs fine in VC++2015.

- Is this a bug of VC++2015?
- Does the standard dictates that `auto` can add implicitly `const`ness to an object when a statement renders the program ill-formed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a bug of VC++2015?

The standard allows implementations to accept code that is ill-formed as extensions. However implementations are still required to issue a diagnostic (which can just mean "emit a warning when certain flags are turned on").

> Does the standard dictates that `auto` can add implicitly constness to an object when a statement renders the program ill-formed?

No, the standard requires `auto` deduction to use the same rules as template argument deduction (with an exception for initializer lists). If `T&` will not accept it, then `auto&` will not.

Answer (score 2):

No, `auto` cannot add constness. However, MSVC++ has always had an extension that non-const lvalue references can bind to rvalues.

You can disable this extension with the `/Za` switch, I think.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a bug of VC++2015?

Redmond-defendants often call it a "feature", but it is a completely stupid bug in that mess of a compiler (fixable with `/Za`). Let's see why...

```
auto &x = bar();
```

Okay, so you are calling `bar()`, no? This produces an `rvalue`, that is, an object without an address. Now, you can't bind an `lvalue` (an object whose address can be obtained) reference (a.k.a: `&`) to an `rvalue`. So far, that's the reason your code is illegal.

However, there's a special rule in the C++ language that allows a `const lvalue` reference to bind to an `rvalue`, effectively extending its lifetime. So, this would be valid code...

```
const auto &x = foo();
```

**Edit**: BTW...

> Does the standard dictates that auto can add implicitly constness to an object when a statement renders the program ill-formed?

To put it in non-standardese terminology/plain English, if `T&` is rejected, so will `auto&`. CV-qualifiers (`const` and `volatile`) are *not* automatically deduced from `auto`.

I hope this has led some light on you!

Comment: "CV-qualifiers (`const` and `volatile`) are not automatically deduced from `auto`." Not quite. `const int c = 1; auto& d = c; /* OK, d is const int & */` It doesn't conjure cv-qualifiers out of thin air, but if the initializer is cv-qualified it's perfectly happy to deduce it

Comment: To @T.C. I would add that it even works with an rvalue: `auto& d = std::move(c)` will compile. But you don't see const-qualified rvalues that much.

Comment: What are you on about? I currently work with GNU/Linux and privately have a Mac, and yet I *have* to defend "Redmond" because compilers are free to accept ill-formed code as extensions (except a warning may be required, as has been mentioned). Whether this particular extension is worthwhile is a different topic. For example, the GCC developers in fact have been as happy to provide extensions as any other compiler team – remember C++ signatures? There's no "pure standard C++" compiler I know of, not even only by default.

Comment: @ArneVogel: GNU/Linux, of course ;). My point is that most of those "features" where reported as bugs long before being claimed as features, not to mention the fact they're barely documented. GCC at least documents `__attribute__(())`...